# why my code is not showing the expected behavior

Tags: java, multithreading

while reading threads i came across following code

```
Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
                int count = 0;
                while (!Thread.interrupted())
                    System.out.println(name + ": " + count++);
            }
        };
        Thread thdA = new Thread(r);
        Thread thdB = new Thread(r);
        thdA.start();
        thdB.start();
        while (true) {
            double n = Math.random();
            if (n >= 0.49999999 && n <= 0.50000001)
                break;
        }
        thdA.interrupt();
        thdB.interrupt();
```

and this code is running smoothly but when I tried to divide this code into methods it is not showing any output , am I doing something wrong?

```
public String runableStatements() {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        int count = 0;
        while (!Thread.interrupted()) {
            System.out.println(name + " : " + count++);
        }
        return name + String.valueOf(count);
    }

    public Runnable runnableTarget(ThreadInteruptionDemo demo) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName());
                demo.runableStatements();
            }
        };
        return r;
    }

    public void startThreads(ThreadInteruptionDemo demo) {
        Thread thOne = new Thread(demo.runnableTarget(demo));
        Thread thTwo = new Thread(demo.runnableTarget(demo));

        thOne.start();
        thTwo.start();

        while (true) {
            double n = Math.random();
            if (n >= 0.49999999 && n <= 0.500000001) {
                System.out.println(n);
                break;
            }
            thOne.interrupt();
            thTwo.interrupt();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      ThreadInteruptionDemo demo = new ThreadInteruptionDemo();
//      demo.startThreads(demo);
```

output for first code

```
Thread-0: 86470
Thread-0: 86471
Thread-0: 86472
Thread-0: 86473
Thread-0: 86474
Thread-0: 86475
Thread-0: 86476
Thread-0: 86477
Thread-0: 86478
Thread-0: 86479
```

while output for second is

Thread-0
Thread-1

What point I'm missing , am I doing something wrong?
If yes then How to solve this?

**EDIT** While debugging second code it doesn't shows any output

Comment: is it right that you interrupt the threads in the loop for the second example while not doing so in the first?

Comment: @KevinEsche , now i got where the error was and Thank you so much :0